# Add a dropdown field in the left to the search field in Laravel nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

In every Laravel Nova resource, there's a Search input field. The columns that should be searched is added like this:

```
/**
 * The columns that should be searched.
 *
 * @var array
 */
public static $search = [
   'id', 'key'
];
```

But, I want the id, key, etc. to be user defined.

How do I add a dropdown (with column names like id, key) left to it so that Search works for the column I entered in that dropdown?

Comment: considering Nova does not send any information about the search fields to the server you would have to build your own component from the nova component to implement your own logic